# Vim spell checking marks "the the" in red. Can I define my own rules like that?

Tags: spell-checking

If spell checking is on and I type "the the" two times in a row, it marks it as an error.  This is described in the docs as Word Combinations.  Can I make my own rules like this?  How is this done?  I imagine `zw` only works on the word you're on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zw` should work just fine. Select the words with Visual mode first. I just verified this myself (Vim 8.0). You can also add them manually by going to the first file you see with `set spellfile?`. Simply put the words on their own line and append `/!`, e.g. `is bad/!`. If they don't appear as a spelling error immediately after `zw` try doing a screen redraw with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

I figured some of this out by doing `:h spell` and then `/the the`. That's the example they use whenever discussing multi-word entries. :)